# onChange and onSelect are not working for Select inside a loop in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, select

I Have a scenario, where i need to have multiple Select tags inside loops, but onselect event is not working for any of them, please find the below code. thanks in advance.

```
const ThirdStepMap = ({csvFields, profileFileds}) => { // last row, no border-bottom class to be added

const [selectData, setSelectData] = useState('');

console.log('selectData', selectData);
return(
    <div className="modal-body no-pad"> 
    <div className="ap-map-head">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col p-0">CSV file field</div>
            <div className="col p-0">Airborne fields</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="ap-map-body">
        {
            csvFields.map(e => {
                return(
                    <div className="row border-bottom">
            <div className="col p-0">
                <div className="form-group static-text d-flex align-items-center">
                    <label for="staticEmail" className=" col-form-label">{e}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col p-0">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <select className="form-control" onChange={(e) => setSelectData(e.target.value)}>
                    {
                        profileFileds.map(r => <option key={r.fieldName} selected={e.toLowerCase().startsWith(r.fieldName.toLowerCase().substr(0,3)) ||  r.fieldName === 'select'} value={r.fieldName}>{r.displayName}</option>)
                    }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                )
            })
        }

    </div>
  </div>
)
```

}

Comment: The handler is called `onChange`, not `onSelect`

Comment: @Jayce444 Onchange too not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not binding the function call with the event. For that you simply need to do

```
<select className="form-control" onSelect={(e) => this.setSelectData.bind(this, e.target.value)}>
```

Comment: Hi Mayank, i am using react hooks, so no need to bind. i think

Comment: But you have not mentioned that anywhere.

Comment: Please find the complete code for this component

updated in question

Answer (score 0):

What is you problem exactly? Does your console.log() statement log the correct value? I believe you just forgot to add the value={selectData} on your select element.